# How to write verbose information into file?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using CURL in my php script and I want to write information from CURLOPT_VERBOSE into file. I tried CURLOPT_STDERR but without luck. It still print everything in cmd window. I'm not sure if parameter in curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $errFileHandle); should be file handler or file name (both not work).

Comment: As for "file handler or file name", the manual clearly says "stream resource (using fopen(), for example)" (i.e. file handle). Do you have error display or logging turned on; if so, what errors do you see; if not, why not? Is the file successfully opened with fopen()? Are you opening it with an absolute or relative path? (If relative, it will be in the current working directory, which you can determine with getcwd()). Can you possibly post your relevant code to help us out?

Comment: @Sten, if the supplied answer answers your question, could you please choose it as your answer so that this long standing question is closed? Thx.

Answer (score 4):

Running on a Unix based OS? Use the below on the command line to run your script. Using Windows OS, use the command on Cygwin.

```
php yourPhp.php > yourFile.txt
```

Or you can just run it in verbose mode with a file handle

```
<?PHP

$verbosPath = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'verboseOut.txt';
echo "Saving verbose output to: $verbosPath\n";

$handle=curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_STDERR,$f = fopen($verbosPath, "w+"));
curl_exec($handle);

fclose($f);
?>
```