# Curl doesn't work with xampp and Php 5.6

Tags: php, curl, xampp

curl doesn't seem to work in my local projects.

This example doesn't display anything for me :

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Exemple d'utilisation de curl</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
// Url de la page dont vous voulez récupérer le contenu (plus précisément : le code source)
$url = 'http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL';
// Initialise une session cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Défini quelques options
// - Indique l'url auquel curl devra accéder
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// - Retourne le contenu par la fonction curl_exec au lieu d'afficher directement le contenu récupéré
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// - Défini un user-agent à envoyer au serveur. Vous pouvez par exemple envoyer un user-agent d'un téléphone Android, d'un iPhone, ... pour tenter de récupérer le contenu d'une version mobile d'un site web
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');
// - Exécute la session cURL fournie et stocke le contenu récupéré dans la variable $resultat (grâce à l'option CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER)
$resultat = curl_exec ($ch);
// - Ferme une session cURL et donc la connexion au serveur distant
curl_close($ch);

// Affiche le contenu récupérer par curl
echo $resultat;

?>


</body>
</html>
```

I use xampp on windows 8. Php 5.6.

I did everything to make it work (some were already done) :

- uncommented extension:php_curl.dll in php.ini file
- uncommented extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"in php.ini
- add these files in c:/xampp/php and -to be sure- in c:/WINDOWS/System32 : ssleay32.dll, libssh2.dll, libeay32.dll
- php_curl.dll is in c:/xampp/php/ext
- ensure the PATH is correctly completed with : C:\xampp\php
- I reboot my computer to be sure everything was correctly initialised

I don't undestand why it still doesn't work... Any idea pleaaaaase ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CURL not working. Wikipedia has a 301 redirect to it's https URL and you're calling the http URL without the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` flag. Even then you probably still have to disable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); because there is a redirect in the wiki page which you are invoking from http to https protocol. This is the only param you need to set and it will work.

Code change

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Exemple d'utilisation de curl</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
// Url de la page dont vous voulez récupérer le contenu (plus précisément : le code source)
$url = 'http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL';
// Initialise une session cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Défini quelques options
// - Indique l'url auquel curl devra accéder
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// - Retourne le contenu par la fonction curl_exec au lieu d'afficher directement le contenu récupéré
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// - Défini un user-agent à envoyer au serveur. Vous pouvez par exemple envoyer un user-agent d'un téléphone Android, d'un iPhone, ... pour tenter de récupérer le contenu d'une version mobile d'un site web
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');
// - Exécute la session cURL fournie et stocke le contenu récupéré dans la variable $resultat (grâce à l'option CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER)
$resultat = curl_exec ($ch);
// - Ferme une session cURL et donc la connexion au serveur distant
curl_close($ch);

// Affiche le contenu récupérer par curl
echo $resultat;

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check in the error log i.e., logs/error_log file for any exceptions. What error you are getting ?  Add these statements to enable debugging. curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out); Ref here for a sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475723/how-to-write-verbose-information-into-file